# Angular project ng build --prod compile failed

Tags: angular, angular-material, production

I entered the following command  **ng build --prod** 
but got the following error in the terminal when I was making a production build for my Angular app.

[image]

I actually don't understand which part of my code has the error after trying to debug. it says in the error that it has something to do with **MatListItem**  but I didn't understand what I need to do.

Comment: looks like corrupted node_modules, can you clean up your node modules and do a fresh install to build the project again

Comment: No @SasiKumarM, it did not resolve the issue. Also, it states "referring to a type without a variable" you know what does this mean?
I assume it means I have not declared a type for one of my variables but I just crossed check and did not find any.